# How to fetch Authorisation Bearer to test APIs from website which needs username and password?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to extract the Authorisation Bearer from my website after logging in by the help of python.

I have username,password and two factor authentication

Please suggest me piece of code by which i can print the authorization bearer token and save it in a variable.

I tried using requests library but it is not giving authorisation bearer in the header

Answer (score 0):

By default, you cannot get the Authorization header from the response which is what you are trying to do. The server needs to expose it by setting the response header `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: authorization`.

My suggestion is to use selenium instead and get it from the logged request headers after you're logged in.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import json
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r"your_path")
har = json.loads(driver.get_log('har')[0]['message']) # get the log
print('headers: ', har['log']['entries'][0]['request']['headers'])
```